# How can I group this in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this selection

```
Trip Sequence Shipment Place
=================================
102  10       4798     Amsterdam
102  20       4823     Utrecht
102  30       4831     Utrecht
102  40       4830     Rotterdam
102  50       4790     Rotterdam
102  60       4840     Utrecht
102  70       4810     Amsterdam
```

I want this grouped like this:

```
 Trip  Group Place
 ==========================
  102  1     Amsterdam
  102  2     Utrecht
  102  3     Rotterdam
  102  4     Utrecht
  102  5     Amsterdam
```

How can I achieve this in SQL server?
Answer of @Giorgos Betos is great. Follow-up question: How can I assign these groupnumbers to the rows of the original table?

Comment: Can you explain the grouping?  Why does Amsterdam and Utrecht appear twice but Rotterdam is only shown once?  Also if you've had a go yourself can you add the SQL, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: your grouping doesnt help much,could you explain how you assigned group numbers  1 to 5

Comment: I think his ' grouping ' means actually to have only one instance when there are more of the same. Is that right @PSVSupporter ?

Comment: Maybe grouping is not the completely correct term for what I mean.
Sequence 20 and 30 are 2 shipments, but are delivered in one 'stop'. So I only want to see this as 1 line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Trip, Place, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MinSequence) AS [Group]
FROM (
  SELECT Trip, Place, MIN(Sequence) AS MinSequence
  FROM (
    SELECT Trip, Place, Sequence,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequence) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Trip, Place 
                              ORDER BY Sequence) AS grp
    FROM mytable) AS x
  GROUP BY Trip, Place, grp) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02400/2)

**Edit:**

To get the ranking numbers in the original, ungrouped, table you can use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT Trip, Place, Sequence,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grp) AS [Group]
FROM (       
  SELECT Trip, Place, Sequence,
         MIN(Sequence) OVER (PARTITION BY Trip, Place, grp) AS grp
  FROM (                          
    SELECT Trip, Place, Sequence,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequence) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Trip, Place 
                              ORDER BY Sequence) AS grp
    FROM mytable) AS t) AS x
ORDER BY Sequence
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02400/12)

Comment: you missed to select *Sequence in your inner select statement. since you are using it in Min(Sequence)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: And now the follow-up: Is there a way to assign those 'group' numbers to invidual lines.
So Trip/Sequence 110/10 = group 1, Trip/Sequence 110/20 = group 2, Trip/Sequence 110/30 = group 2, etc.

Comment: @PSVSupporter I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. You can try posting a follow up question though.

Comment: I mean: In the original table, I should now be able to assign the groupnumbers (see answer) to the rows in the original table. (as extra column) But how can I achieve this?